# Java comparing class instances

Tags: java

I got this code:

```
public Class Car;
{
    private String name;  
    public int number;     


    public Car(String name, int number) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    // this class also got getters and setters
```

Then I got another class:

```
 public class CarList
    {
        private Collection<Car> cars;


        public CarList()
        {
            cars = new HashSet<>();
        }


       public boolean insertCar(Car car)
        {
            return cars.add(car); 
        }
```

Then code continues with some other methods but they are not problem.
If I create two instances of class `Car`, for example `car1(mazda,1)` and `car2(porsche,2)` and then I call method `insertCar`, everything is OK, method returns `true` because there are two cars with different name and number.

But if create for example `car1(mazda,1)` and then `car2(porsche,1)` method returns also `true` despite the fact that numbers of the cars are the same.

EDIT:So my question is how to force method to return `false` when I try to ''add'' cars with the same number AND same name ( so how would @Override equals() method change )?

Comment: You need to implements Car.equals() and Car.hashCode()

Comment: I would be tempted to rename "number" to "id" if it's intended to represent a unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your `Car` class won't compile as it stands. `Class` should be `class`, and you have a semi-colon after `Car`. I would take it as SO mistake only.

For your task, you have to do following modification in your code:

- Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in `Car` class, where you just consider `number` attribute for object comparison, and hashcode calculation.

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object ob) {
      if (!ob instanceof Car) return false;
      Car that = (Car)ob;
      return this.number == that.number;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return number;
  }
  ```
- In `CarList` class, instead of `Collection<Car>` use a `Set<Car>`. That will automatically take care of duplicates. [`Set#add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) methods adds an element into the `Set` only if it doesn't exists (this is tested on the basis of `equals` and `hashCode`, that is why you need to override them). If the element already exists, then it doesn't modify the set, and return `false`, as you wanted. (Oops, missed that you are actually instantiating a `HashSet` only in your class. Better to rename the reference to `Set<Car>`).

---

**Related:**

- [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/1679863)

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I just have another question: how would equals() change when I consider ''number'' && ''name'' attribute for object comparsion?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for you and which is best depends on the usage scenario of your `CarList` class.

The most straight forward modification to your current code is going to be to add some code to the `Add` method to go through all the cars in the list and check whether another car with the same number already exists. If so then don't add and return FALSE.

But the above will have quadratic performance for inserts which would probably not be very good for you.

Instead, a much better alternative would be to use an extra data structure such as a `HasSet` of all the car numbers already in the list. And when adding, check the set for duplicates and if the number you're adding already exists return false.

```
HashSet<Integer> carNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
public boolean insertCar(Car car)
{
    if(!carNumbers.contains(car.getNumber()))
    {
        carNumbers.put(car.getNumber());
        return cars.add(car); 
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override the `equals` method for `Car`. In that method provide the logic you would like to determine whether or not two objects are the same.

```
@override
public boolean equals(Car car) {
   return car.name == this.name && car.number == this.number;
}
```

Or whatever condition you would like the method to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're Java.

You're given two objects, and need to figure whether they're identical. One is Car at memory location 1000000, the other is Cat at 1200000. Look different. Done.

Java does one extra step though: "do the objects have `equals()` method?" If so, it gets called, and the object can itself decide whether it's equal to another. If it doesn't, falls back to "are they the same instance?"

So if you override equals() method, something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
  if (!(ob instanceOf Car)) { return false; }
  Car other = (Cat)ob;
  // decide whether they're equal and return true/false
}
```

Then that's a step in the right direction.

Second part is `hashCode()`. The contract is this:

if a1.equals(a2) then a1.hashCode()==a2.hashCode()

so, identical objects must produce the same hashcode. However, different objects may be producing the same hash code as well.

Comment: what's with that first line?

Answer (score 0):

The HashSet answers will work, but they assume you'll never want two Cars with the same number and different name in any use case.

If you want to use this behaviour in only this use case (e.g. the number is unique inside a CarList, but not in general), you could use a TreeSet with a custom Comparator. As an additional feature, the list will automatically be sorted by the number.

```
cars = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<>(){
    public int compare(Car a, Car b){
       return a.number - b.number;
    }
});
```

In this case, you don't need to implement equals() or hashCode().

Comment: It will avoid duplicates if the compare returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class as follows:
**Car**

```
public class Car {

private String name;
public int number;

public Car(String name, int number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (!(ob instanceof Car)) {
        return false;
    }
    Car car = (Car) ob;
    return this.number == car.number;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return number;
}
}
```

**Car List**

```
public class CarList {

private Set<Car> cars;

public CarList() {
    cars = new HashSet<Car>();
}

public boolean insertCar(Car car) {
    return cars.add(car);
}
```

}

Comment: Code only answer is not acceptable on SO. At least explain why this would work. Apart from that, how is this different from my answer?